# How many ePWM instances are there in a TMS320C28x Piccolo DSP chip?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, signal-processing, dsp

In [this reference manual](http://www.sunist.org/shared%20documents/TRANSISTOR,%20IC,%20CIRCUIT%20...%20DATASHEETS/TMS320x280x%20Enhanced%20Pulse%20Width%20Modulator%20(ePWM)%20Module%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), it is written that:

> [Page 11] 1 Introduction
>   ......
>    Cross coupling or sharing of resources has been avoided; instead, the ePWM is built up from smaller single channel modules with separate resources that can operate together as required to form a system. This modular approach results in an orthogonal architecture and provides a more transparent view of the peripheral structure, helping users to understand its operation quickly.
>
> In this document the letter x within a signal or module name is used to indicate a generic ePWM instance on a device. For example output signals EPWMxA and EPWMxB refer to the output signals from the ePWMx instance. Thus, EPWM1A and EPWM1B belong to ePWM1 and likewise EPWM4A and EPWM4B belong to ePWM4.

My questions are,

- How many ePWM modules are there in one single TMS320C28x Piccolo DSP chip?
- What does it mean by an ePWM instance? Are those software instances or hardware instances?
- How many ePWM instances are there in one single TMS320C28x Piccolo DSP chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ePWM is a single module, which has two outputs, A and B. For this, each module have ePWMxA and ePWMxB.

These outputs are complementary to each other.

For example, if you use a controller with 8 ePWM modules, You have 16 outputs, grouped in 8 pairs.

> My questions are,
>
> How many ePWM modules are there in one single TMS320C28x Piccolo DSP chip?

You must refer to the datasheet of the controller.

> What does it mean by an ePWM instance? Are those software instances or hardware instances?

Is a hardware instance. This instance has two complementary ouputs, A y B.

> How many ePWM instances are there in one single TMS320C28x Piccolo DSP chip?

You must refer to the datasheet of the controller.

All this is detailed on page 1-3 of "Introduction" chapter, from the reference manual you posted.